# Add Custom button in VideoJs player (inside player not in controlbar)

Tags: video.js

I want to insert a skip intro button in my videjs player,Like netflix or youtube skip add button. I have gone through many documentations but found every button on controlbar. Is there any way to add a button over videjs player for skip intro not on control bar.

I have added button using components in videoJs, but it adds the button in controlbar, i want to add the button over player not in the control bar

Comment: I just solved it by creating a custom element but createElement and appending it in Player.el() like this
```     
 player = videojs('video_vdrm', {})
const skipButton = document.createElement('button');       
player.el().appendChild(skipButton);
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's added to the control bar you're doing something like `player.controlBar.addChild('Button', myOptions)`.

Instead you can add it directly to the player, `player.addChild('Button', myOptions)`. You'll need to add some styles since the default styles assume it's a child of the control bar, but this way it's a direct child of the player element.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it by creating a custom element but createElement and appending it in player.el() like this

```
 player = videojs('video_vdrm', {})
const skipButton = document.createElement('button');       
player.el().appendChild(skipButton);
```

here player is the videojs object